# python - how to parse semi structured text (cran.all.1400)

Tags: python, parsing, text-parsing

I need to work with the [cran.all.1400](http://ir.dcs.gla.ac.uk/resources/test_collections/cran/) text file.

It's a collection of abstracts from articles with some aditional data about each article. Its in the form:

.I 1
.T
experimental investigation of the aerodynamics of a
wing in a slipstream .
.A
brenckman,m.
.B
j. ae. scs. 25, 1958, 324.
.W
//a lot of text

.I 2
.T
simple shear flow past a flat plate in an incompressible fluid of small
viscosity .
.A
ting-yili
.B
department of aeronautical engineering, rensselaer polytechnic
institute
troy, n.y.
.W
//lots of text

and so on.

What I need is the data organized like so:

article 1: .T="whatever the title of article 1 is", .A="w/e the author is", .B="w/e", .T="all the text"
article 2: .T="whatever the title is", .A="w/e the author is", .B="w/e", .T="all the text"

How would I go about doing this in Python?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: And what did you try? [Read Question rules here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It looks that you have keywords composed of a dot, an uppercase letter and optional attributes alone on a line and regular lines. Just process the file line by line and come here to ask more precise questions if your are stuck somewhere.

Comment: I tried reading the whole file as a single string (with read) and then breaking the string up using .I as a delimiter. That gave me a list of articles (with a empty element at the start but I can manage that). Now I need to break articles up by the other tags/keywords but still know which element belongs to which article. I suppose I need a dictionary of dictionaries or a table/2D array.

Comment: I don't know how to put lines in the right place if I process the text line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea from the comments of splitting on `.I` seems like a good start.

The following seems to work:

```
with open('crantest.txt') as f:
    articles = f.read().split('\n.I')

def process(i, article):
    article = article.replace('\n.T\n','.T=')
    article = '.T=' + article.split('.T=')[1] #strips off the article number, restored below
    article = article.replace('\n.A\n',',.A=')
    article = article.replace('\n.B\n',',.B=')
    article = article.replace('\n.W\n',',.W=')
    return 'article ' + str(i) + ':' + article

data = [process(i+1, article) for i,article in enumerate(articles)]
```

I created a test file consisting of only the first 10 articles (discarding a small header and all of the file starting with `.I 11`). When I run the above code I get a list of length 10. It is important that the very first line begins `.I` (with no prior newline) since I make no effort to test if the first entry of the split is empty. The first entry in the list is a string that begins:

```
article 1:.T=experimental investigation of the aerodynamics of a\nwing in a slipstream .,.A=brenckman,m.,.B=j. ae. scs. 25, 1958, 324.,.W=experimental investigation of the aerodynamics of a\nwing in a slipstream
```

**On Edit** Here is a dictionary version which uses `partition` to successively pull of the relevant chunks. It returns a dictionary of dictionaries rather than a list of strings:

```
with open('crantest.txt') as f:
    articles = f.read().split('\n.I')

def process(article):
    article = article.split('\n.T\n')[1]
    T, _, article = article.partition('\n.A\n')
    A, _, article = article.partition('\n.B\n')
    B, _, W = article.partition('\n.W\n')
    return {'T':T, 'A':A, 'B':B, 'W':W}

data = {(i+1):process(article) for i,article in enumerate(articles)}
```

For example:

```
>>> data[1]
{'A': 'brenckman,m.', 'T': 'experimental investigation of the aerodynamics of a\nwing in a slipstream .', 'B': 'j. ae. scs. 25, 1958, 324.', 'W': 'experimental investigation of the aerodynamics of a\nwing in a slipstream .\n  an experimental study of a wing in a propeller slipstream was\nmade in order to determine the spanwise distribution of the lift\nincrease due to slipstream at different angles of attack of the wing\nand at different free stream to slipstream velocity ratios .  the\nresults were intended in part as an evaluation basis for different\ntheoretical treatments of this problem .\n  the comparative span loading curves, together with\nsupporting evidence, showed that a substantial part of the lift increment\nproduced by the slipstream was due to a /destalling/ or\nboundary-layer-control effect .  the integrated remaining lift\nincrement, after subtracting this destalling lift, was found to agree\nwell with a potential flow theory .\n  an empirical evaluation of the destalling effects was made for\nthe specific configuration of the experiment .'}
```

`s.partition()` returns a triple consisting of the part of the string `s` before the first occurrence of the delimiter, the delimiter itself, and the part of the string after that occurrence of the delimiter. The underscore (`_`) in the code is a Python idiom which emphasizes that the intend is to discard that part of the return value.

Comment: This is very much closer to what I need. However, my question wasn't clear enough, I'm afraid. I would need the strings broken up as well. I would need some sort of data structure from which I could access, for example, the .W part of the 7th article. A list of lists or something of the sort. I'm still not sure I'm making it clear. But "for i,article in enumerate(articles)" is a great help, I think I get get to where I need to go using that. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you want a list of dictionaries: One dictionary for each article, with each dictionary having keys `'T'`, `'A'` ,`'B'`, and `'W'`.

Comment: Yes, that sounds exactly right! :) I'll try to modify your code to do that later today, there's something else I need to finish first. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Car I added a second approach which is based on dictionaries.

Comment: Wonderful! That's exactly what I needed, perfect! Thank you very much!